# Does the binomial CDF decrease with the number of trials?

Tags: probability, statistics

When we fix the probability of success, does the binomial CDF decrease with the number of trials? I thought so, but I cannot prove it. It would be appreciated if someone could let me know whether it is true and if so, how to prove it. Thanks!

Comment: What exactly do you mean by the CDF decreasing?

Comment: A precise formation could be: let $X_n \sim B(n,p)$ and $n\leq m$. Then is $\mathbb{P}(X_n \leq k) \geq \mathbb{P}(X_m \leq k)$ for all $k$? Is this what you mean to ask?

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2960763/binomial-distribution-stochastic-dominance/3161079#3161079

Comment: Thanks for your clarifying question. Yes, that is exactly what I was asking. Thanks for your help in advance!

Comment: Oh, I just saw the link to the earlier posting. Thanks for the link and sorry for the duplicating question.